# How to filter timestamp column in Data Flow of Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I have timestamp column where I have written following expression to filter the column:

```
contact_date  >= toTimestamp('2020-01-01') && 
contact_date  <= toTimestamp('2020-12-31')
```

It doesn't complain about syntax but after run it doesn't filter based on date specified. Simply to say logic doesn't work. Any idea?

Date Column in Dataset:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't use `toTimestamp()` function. I tested and you will get null output.

I use a [Filter active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-filter) to filter the data. Please use the `toString()` and change the expression like bellow:

```
toString({contact_date })>= toString('2020-01-01') && toString({contact_date })<= toString('2020-12-31')
```

Ref my example, `contact_date` and output:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Works!
So, it requires to convert to string format for the comparison. Don't know..why? Its tricky.

Comment: Actually, toString() is also a function that convert value to date, we can specify the date format. Just according my experience, wo can not compare the timestamp in ADF.

Comment: I see. Thanks much Leon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to either add the hour, minute and second portions of your dates or specify an appropriate format string, as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#totimestamp), "*If the timestamp is omitted the default pattern yyyy-[M]M-[d]d hh:mm:ss[.f...] is used.*"

Comment: The date is exactly in the default format. That'd why I didn't specify format. Please see added screen capture on my question.

Comment: @DineshMadhup  You date *isn't* in the exact default format as you have only included years, months and days, whereas the default also expects hours, minutes and seconds.  Change your filter dates to `'2020-01-01 00:00:00'` format and let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Hi put in and operation or in ()
ie

```
    (contact_date  >= toTimestamp('2020-01-01') &&  contact_date  <= toTimestamp('2020-12-31'))

    or

     AND(contact_date  >= toTimestamp('2020-01-01') , contact_date  <= toTimestamp('2020-12-31'))
```